# How to Turn Off Rubymine Gem Manager?

Tags: ruby, node.js

I have been developing node projects much more often than Ruby projects recently.

I have mostly gotten RubyMine to play nicely with node and NPM, but every time I open a project the event bubble shows `some of the gems required are not installed` and my project does not have a `Gemfile` or any files ending in `.rb`

I know understand the implications of using a Ruby focused IDE but I recall it is just a rebranded version of WebStorm with added Ruby features...

Comment: i thought it was more code related than `programmers`

Answer (score 2):

`preferences` > `Editor` > `Ruby` > `Gems and gem management` > `Missing Gem`

Note: this is on a per project basis. I now have a starter template where I am keep the `.idea` folder and it's contents so that these settings are used for each project.

I am sure the previous answers used to be right. These settings are based on

```
RubyMine 2020.3.2     
Build #RM-203.7148.67, built on January 26, 2021
```

[Screenshot of RubyMine Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPCZQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

`preferences` -> `inspections` -> `Gems` uncheck `missing gems`

Comment: Tried this, still get the same annoying, incorrect, message in the bottom status bar.

Comment: did you apply and save settings and such?

Comment: Applied, saved, restarted.  It is like the option is completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

this did the trick for me:

`Settings` -> `Notifications` -> `Gem Manager` -> `No popup` and uncheck `Log`