# How to disable Gem Manager in Rubymine?

Tags: rubymine

There's no way to do it in here?
I just want to install gems through the terminal.
I'm very confused about this.
Any help would be great.

RubyMine 2017.3.

Comment: Do you mean inspection about missing gems? If yes then you can turn it off in Settings | Editor | Inspections.

Comment: @Olivia I turn off this inspection, but gems installed anyway.

Comment: Does it mean that they're still highlighted in the Gemfile?

Comment: In my experience, changing the settings in inspections does not change the behavior.   The Gem Manager continues to pull new gems and make my Gemfile.lock dirty.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189287/how-to-turn-off-rubymine-gem-manager

Answer (score 0):

Balloon about missing gems and their highlighting in Gemfile can be disabled via corresponding settings:

1. Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications | Gem Manager (no popup and no log)
2. Settings | Editor | Inspections | Gems | Missing gems

Comment: I've disabled those, but Gemfile.lock still gets changed when I add a gem to my Gemfile.

Comment: that's most likely to be caused by `bundle check` being executed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11114